# Notify specific user using web socket in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-websocket, stomp

I am creating a task management application in Spring boot. Following are my models:

```
public class Task {

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private User assignee;

    //getters and setters
}

public class User {

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    //getters and setters
}
```

I'm using spring security for the user. Now say there are three `Users` A, B and C. A creates a `Task` and assigns it to B. I am trying to send a notification only to B at this point using websocket. For this I created a `WebSocketConfiguration`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
        stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/socket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
}
```

The controller to assign this task:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/task")
public class TaskController {

    @PostMapping("/assign")
    public void assign(@RequestBody Task task) {
        taskService.assign(task);
    }
}
```

And finally in the service, I have:

```
@Service
public class TaskService {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @Override
    public void assign(Task task) {
        //logic to assign task
        template.convertAndSendToUser(task.getAssignee().getEmail(), "/topic/notification",
            "A task has been assigned to you");
    }
}
```

In the client side, I'm using Angular and the subscribe portion looks like the following:

```
stompClient.subscribe('/topic/notification'+logged_user_email, notifications => {
    console.log(notifications); 
})
```

Currently, nothing is printed in the console for any of the users.

I followed [this](https://www.stackextend.com/angular/websocket-with-spring-boot-and-angular/) tutorial, which worked perfectly for broadcast message.

I've also used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44933778/spring-boot-web-socket-with-stomp-not-sending-message-to-specific-user#50265667) as a reference for using the logged_user_email, but it doesn't work.

I've tried prefixing `/user` to subscribe to `/user/topic/notification/` in client side as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367223/sending-message-to-specific-user-on-spring-websocket#31577152). I've also tried using `queue` instead of topic as explained in the same answer, but I have found no success.

Other answers I've found mention the use of `@MessageMapping` in the controller but I need to be able to send the notification from the service.

So the question is how do I distinguish which user the notification is intended for and how do I define this in both the server and client sides?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit late but for anyone who's having the same problem, I made it working by doing the following:

Instead of sending the email of the user, I converted it to Base64 and sent.

```
@Service
public class TaskService {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @Override
    public void assign(Task task) {
        //logic to assign task
        String base64EncodedEmail = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(task.getAssignee().getEmail().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        template.convertAndSendToUser(base64EncodedEmail, "/topic/notification",
            "A task has been assigned to you");
    }
}
```

Then in the client side, in the WebSocketService of [this tutorial](https://www.stackextend.com/angular/websocket-with-spring-boot-and-angular/), I replaced the connect method with the following:

```
public connect() {
    const encodedEmail = window.btoa(email);
    const socket = new SockJs(`http://localhost:8080/socket?token=${encodedEmail}`);
    const stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    return stompClient;
}
```

In the subscribe section, I did the following:

```
stompClient.subscribe("/user/topic/notification", notification => {
    //logic to display notification
});
```

Everything else is same as in the tutotial.